# ReactiveUI - WhenAnyObservable throws NotSupportedException: Index expressions are only supported with constants

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I am not sure if I am using WhenAnyObservable correctly.  My understanding of WhenAnyObservable is that it, more or less, protects you by handling any changes in the property chain you are observing?  But when I try to do this:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(y => y.SelectedLocation))
    .Subscribe(x => // Do something here);
```

I get the exception described in the title.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is my understanding of WhenAnyObservable way off base?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
this.WhenAnyObservable(x => x.ViewModel.SelectedLocation)
```

Comment: The compiler complains when I try to do that because the SelectedLocation property is not an observable.  I attempted to turn it in to an observable with `x.ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(y => y.SelectedLocation)`.

Comment: Do you want to just know when a property changes?

Comment: It's 3 years later and this is still an issue, is there another way to listen to 2 observables that doesn't require WhenAnyObservable?